# Given a value at a point on the curve , how to approximate values at other points at the curve

Tags: math, curve-fitting, curve, discrete-mathematics, calculus

I have a trend of graph whose equation is not known to me , its plotted in xy plane where x denotes time which is 1 to 96 (representing 15 mins period) and y denotes the value at given x. I am given a value of y at given x say ( 4 , 30). Now I need to trace the curve and find the values of y for all other x.

Any idea how it can be done using calculus and how do I program for it ?

I am trying to do using applying tangent lines but I am not entirely able to think it through.

Example: Suppose I plot a graph using x,y values , it will be a asymmetric curve. Now once the curve is drawn. The same curve can be used to approximate values on different data set which show the same trend of curve. So if I am given only one point say y = 40 at x= 10 , how do I get values of Y for other x for the data set showing similar trend of curve.

```
1,6.81
2,5.516
3,6.088
4,8.025
5,6.89
6,9.98
7,8.511
8,8.458
9,8.172
10,8.467
11,10.294
12,11.106
13,10.517
14,7.905
15,8.141
16,9.608
17,8.774
```

Comment: I'd ask in math.stackexchange.com firstly

Comment: I don't think you can find a function when you only know one point...

Comment: what curve? in what form? (image (raster/vector?),set of points,...) add example  of what data you have

Comment: added an example to clear my problems.

Comment: You can't "make" a function out of one point. You need at least two points, but that's still not enough, you need to know what your function should look like (linear function, polynomial...). Once you have these you can use standard machine learning techniques to fit the form of your function of choice to the data. For linear function it is easy using linear regression. For polynomials it is also easy by transforming the input and then using linear regression.

Comment: @Jan Zegklitz please check my example , I have all the points and I have the curve. But I dont know the equation of it.  Now I want to use the same curve to approximate values based on a given point.

Comment: @Bankelaal So what's your case then? Do you have only one point or do you have a bunch of these like in the example at the bottom? And what do you mean by that you have the curve but not the equation? Do you, in fact, mean that you have an equation but you don't know some coeffitients? Please state what is your input and what do you expect as the output in the most clear and simple way.  Now I'm only confused and don't know how should I help.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "trend". If both data sets vary by a constant scale, you can just multiply all data points with the constant (in the example, `40/8.467`). If it is shifted, you need to add a constant value (in the example, `40-8.467`). Basically, with one data point, you can express any transformation with one degree of freedom. Other transformations (e.g. scale + shift) require more data points.

Comment: @Jan Zegklitz Sorry for that , Let me try to explain again. I get data from a outside system every 15 minutes each day. So when I plot a graph of time Vs value of data on a given day , I get a asymmetric curve. Now its obvious that I only have data and I can plot it and it will be mostly a curve and I dont know the equation. Now I have another object which shows similar daily trend but I dont have values for each x,y , I only have one point (x,y) so how do I use the initial data set to get  all the other x and y which fits to this one new point.

Comment: I am looking for an approximation algorithm , I realize I may not get the exact values with a trend and one value. All I am looking for a best approximation method.

Comment: @Bankelaal Ok I understand now. Could you plase edit your question so that it is absolutely clear for everyone what you ask for? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**So the 2 graphs are the same or scaled or shifted between each other?**

let `(x,y)` be your wanted point `x` is known `y` is unknown

let `(xx,yy)` be the known point in the second graph/data

let the known graph be source graph

[image: example]

So:

1. **the same graphs**

   find closest 2 points in source data `(x0,y0),(x1,y1)` where `x0<=x` and `x<x1`. Interpolate between them for example by linear interpolation:

   ```
   y=y0+(y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0)
   ```
2. **scaled graphs**

   compute scaled source graph so compute `yy'` from source graph for `xx` via bullet **#1**. The scale `m=yy/yy'` so `yy=yy'*m` Now just compute `y'` from source graph for `x` via bullet **#1** and convert to scale of destination graph so `y=y'*m`
3. **shifted graphs**

   for these you need to know either the shift offset or more points from second graph. Shift can occur in both `x` and `y` axis so You need to apply both offset corrections `xo,yo`. Where `y=y'+yo` and `x=x'+xo` to transfer between graphs.

   So you find `y'` for `(x-xo)` and then `y=y'+yo`
4. **scaled and shifted graphs**

   simply combine bullets **#2,#3**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two tasks:

1. Given a set of points, you are looking for a model.

   1. Structure of the model.
   2. Parameters of the model.
2. Using the previous model, tune its parameters so that it fits new point(s).

So, one step at a time...

**1. Structure and paremeters**

This is hard. You have basically two options.

1. You can choose a structure manually, e.g. a linear model (i.e. an equation of a form `y = a*x + b`) or a polynomial model (i.e. an equation of a form `y = c_n * x^n + c_n-1 * x^n - 1 + ... + c_0` but you have to choose `n` too). Or a neural network (where you have to fix the topology).

   If you do this, the parameters fitting is easy (if you have a sane model like the ones I mentioned). Especially for linear and polynomial models look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).
2. Let some algorithm find a structure. If you are willing to stay in the ralm of neural network, you can use [NEAT](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html) or [HyperNEAT](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/hyperNEATpage/HyperNEAT.html). Or if you really need a symbolic description, you can use [Genetic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) and similar algorithms. Or if you want a polynomial but you don't know the degree, you can just try several of them.

**2. Pameter tuning to new data**

Well, for this to work you need a model that allows parameter tuning and then you need enough data the model needs to be tuned. For linear model this is at least 2 points. For a polynomial the number is equal to the degree + 1 (or to the number of coeffitients).

If you used something like genetic programming, you are probably out of luck because it is just a fitted symbolic expression which you can't tune using some parameters, but you can perform any transformation on the whole expression (e.g. a linear one, or a polynomial...). Or you can use a variant of GP, called Multi-Gene Genetic Programming (an implementation in MATLAB is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gptips4matlab/), which has parameters that can be tuned.

If you have less new data than required for the model, you must fix some parameters manually, e.g. for the linear model you could say that the slope remains the same and only the constant part is going to be fitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Genetic Programming (GP) or one of its variants. I have a simple to use software named Multi Expression Programming X http://www.mepx.org that discovers such functions. I have loaded your data in the program and I have a have obtained the following C function:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void mepx(double *x /*inputs*/, double *outputs)
{
//constants ...
  double constants[5];
  constants[0] = 0.429823;
  constants[1] = -0.327464;
  constants[2] = -0.389508;
  constants[3] = -0.315653;


constants[4] = 0.166875;

  double prg[22];
  prg[0] = x[0];
  prg[1] = cos(prg[0]);
  prg[2] = constants[4];
  prg[3] = prg[0] + prg[1];
  prg[4] = pow(10, prg[1]);
  prg[5] = sin(prg[0]);
  prg[6] = -prg[1];
  prg[7] = constants[4];
  prg[8] = atan(prg[3]);
  prg[9] = prg[4] * prg[6];
  prg[10] = prg[5] > prg[9]?prg[5] : prg[9];
  prg[11] = prg[6] < prg[7]?prg[6] : prg[7];
  prg[12] = atan(prg[10]);
  prg[13] = tan(prg[4]);
  prg[14] = prg[13] - prg[12];
  prg[15] = x[0];
  prg[16] = prg[8] / prg[2];
  prg[17] = sin(prg[14]);
  prg[18] = prg[16] - prg[11];
  prg[19] = prg[18] + prg[17];
  prg[20] = prg[6] / prg[15];
  prg[21] = prg[19] - prg[20];

  outputs[0] = prg[21];
}

int main(void)
{

//example of utilization ...

  double x[1];
  x[0] = 1.000000;

  double outputs[1];

  mepx(x, outputs);
  printf("%lf", outputs[0]);
  getchar();
}
```

The error of that function (distance to your data) is 0.32. You can obtain more if you play with the parameters of the program.

What you have to do now is to provide other inputs to the function (other x) and you will obtain other y.